# Shell Code executes directly, but not in PythonScript

Tags: python, function, shell, beautifulsoup

I wrote a little **Python** function that uses the **BeatifulSoup** libary.  The function should return a list of symbols from a **Wikipedia** article.

In the Shell, I execute the function like this:

```
pythonScript.my_function()
```

...it throws a error in line 28:

```
No connections adapters were found for 'link'.
```

When I type the same code from my function directly in the shell, it works perfectly.  With the same link.  I have even copied and pasted the lines.

These are the two lines of code I'm talking about, the error appears with the **BeautifulSoup** function.

```
response = requests.get('link')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

I can't explain why this error happens...

EDIT: here is the full code

```
#/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#insert_symbols.py

from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
from math import ceil

import bs4
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests

def obtain_parse_wiki_snp500():
    '''
    Download and parse the Wikipedia list of S&P500
    constituents using requests and BeatifulSoup.

    Returns a list of tuples for to add to MySQL.
    '''
#Stores the current time, for the created at record
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

#Use requests and BeautifulSoup to download the
#list of S&P500 companies and obtain the symbol table
response = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/list_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

I think that must be enough. This is the point where the error occurs.
In the Shell Ive done everthing step by step:
importing the libaries and then calling the requests and bs4 function.
The single difference is that in the Shell I didnt defined a function for that.

**EDIT2:**

**Here is the exact Error Message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/felix/Dokumente/PythonSAT/DownloadSymbolsFromWikipedia.py", line 28, in obtain_parse_wiki_snp500

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "/home/felix/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/home/felix/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 570, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)

**File "/home/felix/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 644, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'htttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/list_of_S%26P_500_companies'**

Comment: Please post your actual code, enough of it to actually see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have passed a link with a `htttp`, i.e you have three t when there should be just two, that code would error wherever you run it. The correct url is:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/list_of_S%26P_500_companies
```

Once you fix the url the request works fine:

```
n [1]: import requests


In [2]: requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/list_of_S%26P_500_companies')
Out[3]: <Response [200]>
```

To get the symbols:

```
n [28]: for tr in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable tr + tr"):
             sym = tr.select_one("a.external.text")
             if sym:
                print(sym.text)
   ....:         
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ACN
ATVI
AYI
ADBE
AAP
AES
AET
AFL
AMG
A
GAS
APD
AKAM
ALK
AA
AGN
ALXN
ALLE
ADS
ALL
GOOGL
GOOG
MO
AMZN
AEE
AAL
AEP
```

and so on ...............

Comment: I have checked it but in my script there is no space.. must gone something wrong while pasted it here in stackOverflow.

Comment: In the Stack Overflow Editor the Link was seperated because it were to long. Maybe because of this the space appeared.

Comment: @feliz, there is no htttp protocol it is http

Comment: Ive looked for that. Since the link in my script is without the triple t.. Must be an other error

Comment: Nope, you 100 percent have the wrong URL in your script. Make sure you are running what you think you are